# Method for an accounting program

Tags: java, object, accounting

I'm trying to write an accounting program in Java, for this I need to write a method which expects an accounting record from the prompt.

```
System.out.println("Write your accounting record"); 

String accountingRecord= console.nextLine();

String[] parts= accountingRecord.split(" ");
// Split the String into three parts (debit,credit and ammount)

debit =parts[0];
// the debit could be an account which is declared before e.g. "Bank, Liabilities...
credit=parts[1];
//should be too an account which is declared before.

int ammount= Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

account.accounting(debit,credit,ammount);
```

Now to come to my question, the Static method "accounting" expects two objects, the debit and the Credit Object (e.g. Bank, Liabilities) and of course the amount. How can i type in the Prompt the name of an object?

Comment: You probably are supposed to create the `Credit` and `Debit` objects in your code, e.g. `Credit c = new Credit(credit)`

Comment: I have done that in a step before e.g. with a mortage account `System.out.println("Type the name of the account);
                String nameMortage= console.nextLine();
                LiabilityAccount Mortage= new LiabilityAccount(nameMortage);`

Comment: You are expecting 3 variables in 1 line. What if someone misses any variable - how you are going to determine which input he missed ? I do not think that your approach is correct here, i can see few flaws in the design.